# rxjs: wrap success/fail parameterized lambdas into an observable

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm using a library that exports this function:

```
export function read(
    urlOrRequest: any,
    success?: (data: any, response: any) => void,
    error?: (error: Object) => void,
    handler?: Handler,
    httpClient?: Object,
    metadata?: Object): any;
```

Currently, I'm using this like:

```
var request =
{
    headers: oHeaders,
    requestUri: "http://odatasampleservices.azurewebsites.net/V4/OData/OData.svc/Products",
    data: null,
};

var successFunction = function(data)
{
    document.getElementById("simpleReadWithMetadata").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(data, undefined, 2);
};

var failFunction = function(err)
{
    alert(JSON.stringify(err));
};

oData.read(request, successFunction, failFunction, null, null, metadata);
```

So, my question is, can I wrap this call using rxjs? I guess it's possible but I don't quite figure out how to get it... Any ideas?

Comment: It is possible. Why do you want to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Rx.Observable.create` to wrap the callbacks like so:

```js
function mockRead(urlOrRequest, success, error, handler, httpClient, metadata) {
  if (urlOrRequest === 'success') {
    success('data', 'response');
  } else {
    error('oops...');
  }
}

function read(urlOrRequest, success, error, handler, httpClient, metadata)
{
  return Rx.Observable.create(o => {
    mockRead(
      urlOrRequest,
     (data, response) => {
       o.next({ data, response });
       o.complete();
     },
      (error) => {
       o.error(error);
     },
      handler,
      httpClient,
      metadata
    );
  });
}

read('success')
  .subscribe(
   x => { console.log('next', x); },
   x => { console.log('error', x); },
   () => { console.log('complete'); }
  );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.min.js"></script>
```